Is homology distributive over addition of maps in a homotopy set?
Let $K$ be a co-H group with homotopy commutative comultiplication $\mu$ and $(X,x_0)$ be a pointed space. Denote $H_\ast$ to be the singular homology with integer coeffients. Take $f,g\in[K,X]$, does equation $H_\ast(f+g)=H_\ast(f)+H_\ast(g)$ hold in general? When using the definition of addition operation by $K\stackrel{\mu}{\longrightarrow}K\vee K\stackrel{f\vee g}{\longrightarrow}X\vee X\stackrel{\Delta}{\longrightarrow}X$ where $\Delta$ is the folding map given by $\Delta(x,x_0)=x=\Delta(x_0,x)$, I get that $H_\ast(\Delta(f\vee g))=H_\ast(f)+H_\ast(g)$, but I have no idea about the induced map $H_\ast(\mu)$.

You seem to already know how to describe the homology groups of a wedge sum in general. Now, the composite of $\mu$ and either projection $K\vee K\rightarrow K$ is homotopic to the identity (by definition of a co-H group). You can describe $H_{\ast}(\mu)$ by using this observation.
